# How to pass argumets to RunDeck Run API

Tags: rundeck

I want to run a rundeck job using the run API. Would like to pass few parameters as well to the runDeck job during the run time.

Do I need to configure the job to accept parameters?
How to pass parameters to run API?

Thanks in advance

Regards
SJ

Answer (score 10):

**Option 1:** In absence of tokens, first login to get cookie

```
curl \
  -D - \
  -X POST \
  -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
  -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" \
  -d "j_username=${RD_USER}&j_password=${RD_PASSWORD}" \
  --cookie-jar rd_cookie \
  "${RD_URL}/j_security_check"
```

Then, use the cookie received from successful login for subsequent transactions

```
curl \
  -D - \
  -X "POST" \
  -H "Accept: application/json" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d "{\"argString\":\"-arg1 val1 -arg2 val2 -arg3 val-3 -arg4 val4 \"}" \
  --cookie "@rd_cookie" \
  "${RD_URL}/api/16/job/${RD_JOB_ID}/executions"
```

**Option 2:** With a token, it's simpler

```
curl \
  -D - \
  -X "POST" -H "Accept: application/json" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "X-Rundeck-Auth-Token: ${RD_TOKEN}" \
  -d "{\"argString\":\"-arg1 val1 -arg2 val2 -arg3 val-3 -arg4 val4 \"}" \
  "${RD_URL}/api/16/job/${RD_JOB_ID}/executions"
```

Answer (score 2):

The API documentation for Rundeck describes how to run a job:

- http://rundeck.org/docs/api/#running-a-job

Yes you need to create a parametrized job and pass in arguments as part of the API call. This could be considered a security measure only expected parameters can be accepted.

Comment: This answer could benefit from a tangible curl/wget example